# Installing a Printer using Playonlinux

Tags: playonlinux

I have installed office home 2007 using Playonlinux.

It installed and worked perfectly.

The only thing that doesn't work is the printer. I have installed my printer on my Ubuntu 16 and thats ok. I assume Playonlinux needs to be configured to run the printer to.

Can anybody help with what to do or direct me to instructions on what to do?

Kind Regards

Ian

Comment: You don't "install drivers" with WINE, that's not how it works. Maybe you could just export to pdf, have never used MS Office on WINE. Did you check in the WINE app database?

Comment: Hi Wine didn't work installing Office 2007 home and student, so we used playonlinux instead. I could just use libreoffice but would like to use the 2007 instead.

Comment: Play on Linux is a WINE fronted.

Answer (score 4):

PlayOnLinux is a front-end for Wine.  Wine actually uses CUPS to print.  You might need to configure CUPS for your printer of choice so you can print from your Wine applications.

First, make sure CUPS is installed:

```
sudo apt install cups
```

After CUPS is installed, you can access the CUPS admin page from a web browser by accessing the following address:

http://127.0.0.1:631

Check the printers tab to see if any printer has been added:

[image]

If you have a printer, then you should be good to print.  If not, add one by clicking on the Administration tab.  Then click on the Add Printer button:

[image]

Next, it should come up and show you all printers on your system.  Click the printer you want to use:

[image]

Click continue.  It should be now showing you the information about your printer.

[image]

If it all looks good, click continue again.  Now you get more information.

[image]

If that looks good, now click Add Printer button.  It should bring you to the default settings.

[image]

Click Set Default Options.  Now your printer should be added.

[image]

You will need to close all Wine apps first.  Now, in your Office 2007 apps, when you print you should now see the printer to print to.

[image]

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx, I'm using MS Office 2016. And needed to make PDF from Excel. I was not able to do it because I had no printers installed. cups-pdf solved it for me.