How do I specify a printer in a Wine bottle?
I'm using software in Wine that suddenly won't generate printable files because it says I haven't selected a printer.  How do I select a printer in a Wine bottle?  I don't see where it gives me that option.

Possible solution:  https://askubuntu.com/a/866860/231142
